# Element disappears on certain dimensions

Tags: html, css

I have this [website](https://avsautomotive.com/en/homepage/) and my problem is with the language switcher on top.

As you can see from the screenshots, when  the width is between 768 - 990 px the top bar disappears.

[With top bar at 1175px x 621px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48hF1.png)

[Without top bar at 896px x 489px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjeQK.png)

I have tried many css tricks that i found online, like 
*-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);*
but i still have the same result

The HTML code is the menu from the website. I think the problem is being created by the class="style2"

P.S. At line 6315 of the css you can see the 
**@media (min-width: 768px) {...}**
but i can't figure if something contributes to my problem.

```html
<?php if((get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact') || get_theme_mod('andaman_menu_soc')) == true)  { ?>
<div class="header style2">  
  <div class="top_bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <?php if(get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact') == true)  { ?>
            <ul class="contacts-top">
              <?php if(get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact_address', 'enable') == true)  { ?><li><?php echo esc_attr(get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact_address', '455 Martinson, Los Angeles')); ?></li><?php }; ?> 
              <?php if(get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact_phone', 'enable') == true)  { ?><li><a href="tel:<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '',get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact_phone', '+1 (043) 567-8930')); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr(get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact_phone', '+1 (043) 567-8930')); ?></a></li><?php }; ?> 
              <?php if(get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact_hours', 'enable') == true)  { ?><li><?php echo esc_attr(get_theme_mod('andaman_top_contact_hours', 'Mon-Sut: 10 AM-8 PM')); ?></li><?php }; ?> 
            </ul>
          <?php }; ?> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="soc-top">
              <?php if ( is_plugin_active( 'polylang/polylang.php' )) { ?>
     <li class="lang"><span><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/images/lang-' . pll_current_language('slug') . '.png'; ?>" width="24" height="24" alt=""> <?php echo pll_current_language('name'); ?></span>
                    <ul class="lang-ul">
                    <?php $languages = pll_the_languages( array('raw'=> true, 'hide_if_no_translation'=>true, 'hide_current'=>true) ); 
                      foreach ($languages as $language )  {
                        echo '<li><a href="'.$language['url'].'"><img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/images/lang-'.$language['slug'].'.png" width="24" height="24" alt="'.$language['slug'].'">' .$language['name'].'</a></li>'; }; ?>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
            <?php }; ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } else { ?>
  <div class="header style2 no-bar">
<?php };?>
<div class="sticky-menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-flex">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" rel="home">
          <?php if(get_theme_mod('andaman_logo_upload', 'enable') == true)  { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('andaman_logo_upload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/logo.png')); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" style="height: <?php echo esc_attr(get_theme_mod('andaman_logo_height', '45px')); ?>;">
          <?php } else { ?>
            <h1 style="margin:0;"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
          <?php } ?>
        </a>
      </div>
       <?php if(get_theme_mod('andaman_menu_select', 'standard') == 'standard')  { ?> 
                  <div class="menu-responsive desktop">
                    <div class="navbar-main-collapse pull-left responsive-menu">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                              'theme_location' => 'menu',
                              'container' => false,
                              'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                              'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                              'walker' => new Andaman_My_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
                              'fallback_cb' => 'andaman_MenuFallback'
                            )); ?> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="menu-responsive mobile">
                    <div class="burger_andaman_normal_holder"><a href="#" class="nav-icon3" id="open-button"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></a></div>
                      <div class="burger_andaman_menu_overlay_normal">
                        <div class="burger_andaman_menu_vertical">
                          <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'menu',
                            'menu_class' => 'burger_andaman_main_menu',
                            'depth' => 3,
                          )); ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              <?php } else { ?>
                  <div class="menu-responsive desktop">
                    <div class="navbar-main-collapse pull-left responsive-menu">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                              'theme_location' => 'onepage-menu',
                              'container' => false,
                              'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav share-class',
                              'menu_id' => 'menu-onepage',
                              'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                              'walker' => new Andaman_My_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
                              'fallback_cb' => 'andaman_MenuFallback'
                            )); ?> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="menu-responsive mobile">
                    <div class="burger_andaman_normal_holder"><a href="#" class="nav-icon3" id="open-button"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></a></div>
                      <div class="burger_andaman_menu_overlay_normal">
                        <div class="burger_andaman_menu_vertical">
                          <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'onepage-menu',
                            'menu_class' => 'burger_andaman_main_menu share-class',
                            'menu_id' => 'menu-onepage',
                            'depth' => 1,
                          )); ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              <?php } ?>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because one of your stylesheet hiding the `li.lang` between mentioned width, I have provided you CSS, you can paste it inside the stylesheet.

```
@media screen and (max-width:990px){
   li.search, li.lang {
      display: block !important;
   }
}
```

Screenshot of your CSS: (You have to change `display: none` to `display: block`)

[image]

Comment: Work like a charm! 
Thank you very much!!

Comment: You are welcome, Please hit the tick to make sure my answer really works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gamers Agenda for your quick and accurate answer.

The changes I made with your help:

```
@media screen and (max-width:990px){
       .soc-top {
          float: right;
          margin-right: 30px;
       }
       li.search, li.lang {
          display: block !important;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do:

Your style:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.header.style2 .soc-top {
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

remove `float: none !important;` and be like:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
    .header.style2 .soc-top {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I didn't try your solution but thank you anyway!

Comment: @nikhil, he is facing the issue from 990px to 768px! how come your css for 767px will solve this issue?